Snowflake equivalent for Quotename() in SQL Server?
What would be the equivalent function for quotename() ?
Below is part of a stored procedure:
declare @numcols nvarchar(max)

select @numcols = string_agg(quotename(NAME), ', ') within group (order by NAME)
from 
    (select distinct NAME from #parsednum) as names

I need to convert this code to snowflake equivalent where #parsednum is a temp table. Thanks in advance

I don't believe there is any built-in equivalent. As I understand it, that function exists purely to turn a string into a valid identifier in sql server. Are you wanting to turn a string into a valid Snowflake identifier, or still get out valid sql server identifiers as output?

When I checked those temp table results, I believe I need all the values from name column to be enclosed by a delimiter and use a listagg instead of string_agg provided. That is what my understanding is here.

The quotename seems to just account for delimiter character being part of string by wrapping values into square brackets before building the list. There is no SF equivalent function for this but you could use array_agg, which automatically takes care of that.

Array_agg function worked as expected and even list_agg did return same expected result

Because QUOTENAME() is so specific to SQL Server in that it turns strings into  sql server object names, there won't be a 1:1 replacement in Snowflake. If the square brackets are important for encapsulation you could use array_agg() and array_to_string() functions to get close to what your string_agg(quotename()) is doing:
'[' || ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(NAME), '], [') || ']'

The nice thing about this is that if you don't want square brackets as your encapsulation character, you could change this really easily to anything you like, like double quotes:
'"' || ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(NAME), '", "') || '"'

The caveat here is that QUOTENAME() does more than just encapsulate. It also escapes control characters inside of the string. If that is important, you can hit your NAME column with some regex before running through the ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG()) functions.

Thanks this worked as well list_agg returned same expected result.

Now I do have issue when I try to use pivot with above derives result. It throws invalid identifier ‘some value’ when using below query inside a stored procedure Create or replace temp table as
Select *
From parsednum
Pivot(
Max(value) for name in (||numcols||))c

Is that numcols the output of this logic? If so, is this sql CREATE OR REPLACE being built in a string and executed dynamically? If so, is this procedure in Snowflake? If so, are you still encapsulating column names with square brackets (something that is only relevant in a microsoft sql server or access database)?

That's awesome, I did walkthrough and executed them as dynamic sql in snowflake, and they work now. Encapsulated the numcol values inside single quotes and executing dynamically solved above issue.

Perfect! Glad to hear you got it all working. That's not easy stuff.

This is another case in continuation of above case ** sql_text_transposed := '
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE transposed as
select
a.DATA_KEY as data_key,
' || allcols || ' as allcols
from transposednum AS a
left join transposedchar AS b
on a.DATA_KEY = b.DATA_KEY
        ';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_text_transposed; ** This throws missing column specification

